# finding prime numbers between a range in C

Tags: c, factors

I am trying to find the prime numbers in a range using C language. My code does not give an output and I think there is a logical error here which I cannot figure out. Can anyone please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int lowerLevel;
    int upperLevel;
    int i; //counter variable
    int prime = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    printf("Enter the lower limit and upper limit of the range followed by a comma :");
    scanf("%d %d", &lowerLevel, &upperLevel);

    for (i = 2; i <= upperLevel; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("%d", i);
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well. `i` starts at `2`, and the first thing your loop does is test for `i % 2 == 0` and if true, break the loop. Since `2 % 2 == 0` is true, that's it. Loop breaks, `flag` is `1` now, so that `printf` is skipped, and program exits. The pointless increment of `i` is also skipped, btw. Did you try running your program in a *debugger*, because this would have been obvious on the first step-through.

Comment: Sure - add printf statements to log the progress and/use a debugger to step and inspect.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not check for prime numbers, it merely checks that there is at least one even number between `2` and `upperlevel`, which is true as soon as `upperlevel >= 2`. If there is such an even number, nothing is printed.

You should instead run a loop from `lowerlevel` to `upperlevel` and check if each number is a prime and if so, print it.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int lowerLevel, upperLevel;

    printf("Enter the lower limit and upper limit of the range: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &lowerLevel, &upperLevel) != 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = lowerLevel; i <= upperLevel; ++i) {
        int isprime = 1;
        for (int p = 2; p <= i / p; p += (p & 1) + 1) {
            if (i % p == 0) {
                isprime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime) {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This method is simplistic but achieves the goal. More efficient programs would use a sieve to find all prime numbers in the range without costly divisions.

Comment: Surely it would be better to only consider odd numbers?

Comment: i.e. before first for loop add `lowerLevel += loweLevel & 1` and `upperLevel -= upperLevel & 1`

Comment: Then `++i` to `i += 2` ditto for `p`

Comment: and `int p = 2` to `int p = 3`

Comment: @EdHeal: there are many ways to improve this algorithm. Special casing `2` is possible, but `2` must be printed if it is in the range.

Comment: Just thought it was an easy way to improve the algorithm without much effort

Comment: Could use `int isprime = i > 1;` to not identify values less than 2 as a prime.

Comment: @EdHeal Useful idea to focus on off `i`, yet in extreme cases `lowerLevel += loweLevel & 1` overflows. IMO, best not to assume user input is limited to a nice range.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: another issue: if `upperLevel == INT_MAX`, the loop has undefined behavior after reaching the upper limit.

Answer (score 2):

#### Optimal method with Sieves of Eratosthenes

You should use the sieves of [Eratostenes algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), it is way more efficient to get the different prime number.

> it does so by iteratively marking as composite (i.e., not prime) the multiples of each prime, starting with the first prime number, 2

Basically you consider all numbers prime by default, and then you will set as false the prime number, see below code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/// unsigned char saves space compared to integer
#define bool    unsigned char
#define true    1
#define false   0
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
void printPrimesRange(int lowerLevel, int n) {
    if (lowerLevel < 0 || n < lowerLevel) // handle misused of function
        return ;
    bool isPrime[n + 1];
    memset(isPrime, true, n + 1);
    int cnt = 0; // NB: I use the counter only for the commas and final .\n, its optional.

    if (lowerLevel <= 2 && n >= 2) { // only one even number can be prime: 2
        ++cnt;
        printf("2");
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= n ; i+=2) { // after what only odd numbers can be prime numbers
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            if (i >= lowerLevel) {
                if (cnt++)
                    printf(", ");
                printf("%d", i); // NB: it is better to print all at once if you can improve it
            }
            for (int j = i * 3; j <= n; j+=i*2) // Eratosthenes' Algo, sieve all multiples of current prime, skipping even numbers
                isPrime[j] = false;
        }
    }
    printf(".\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int lowerLevel;
    int upperLevel;

    printf("Enter the lower limit and upper limit of the range with a space in-between:"); // space, not comma
    scanf("%d %d", &lowerLevel, &upperLevel);
    printPrimesRange(lowerLevel, upperLevel);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid `memset(isPrime, true, n + 1);` is incorrect: `bool` is not necessarily defined as a character type in C. You should define `isPrime` as an array of `unsigned char`, and defining it with automatic storage is risky if `upperLevel` is larger than a few millions.

Comment: You should add a test `if (i >= lowerLevel) { ... }` to only print prime numbers inside the range :)

Comment: Wouldnt stdbool.h be okay for that? (See header). For second remark: Indeed! Then we can start from `int i = lowerLevel | 1; `

Comment: `<stdbool.h>` only defines `bool` as `#define bool _Bool`. `_Bool` may be larger than `char`, which means your `memset(isPrime, true, n + 1);` may initialize only a portion of the array and to a value different from `1`.

Comment: For the second remark, starting at `int i = lowerLevel | 1;` is incorrect because multiples of smaller numbers will not have been removed from the array, hence you will output many non primes that will still have `isPrime[i]` set.

Comment: yes I was thinking about that, please let me know if you agree with final edit

Comment: The last loop should start at `j = i * i` but, to avoid overflow, you could write `j  = i * 3`. If you write `j = i`, the `isPrime[i]` will be set to `0` even if `i` is prime. No consequence here, but not a correct sieve. A more efficient sieve would iterate the outer loop only up to and including `(int)sqrt(n)`, calculated before the loop, and start the inner loop at `j = i * i`. A separate loop from `lowerLevel` to `upperLevel` would output the primes. Note that it is more efficient to use trial division if the range is small compared to its upper boundary, small meaning around 1/500 at 1e9.

Comment: I would also change `if (lowerLevel <= 2 && n >= 2 && ++cnt) printf("2");` to `if (lowerLevel <= 2 && n >= 2) { cnt++; printf("2"); }`. The test `&& ++cnt` is confusing as it is not needed and only written as a test to avoid braces. Abstain from such tricks that obfuscate the code.

Comment: ok agree with everything, see final (hopefully) edit.

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the logic of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int lowerLevel;
    int upperLevel;
    int i; //counter variable
    int prime = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    printf("Enter the lower limit and upper limit of the range followed by a comma :");
    scanf("%d %d", &lowerLevel, &upperLevel);

    for (i = 2; i <= upperLevel; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("%d", i);
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

First of all, you have a loop:

```
    for (i = 2; i <= upperLevel; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

this loop tries to find a number `i` that is a multple of `2`, because as soon you get one, you jump out of the loop.  So your loop can be expressed better as:

```
    for (i = 2; i <= upperLevel && i % 2 != 0; ++i) {
    }
    /* i > upperLevel || i % 2 == 0 */
    if (i <= upperLevel && i % 2 == 0) {
        flag = 1;
    }
```

We still need to check if `i <= upperLevel && i % 2 == 0` to set the variable `flag = 1` if we exited the loop because `i` was a multiple of `2`, but the `break;` is not necessary because we are already out of the loop.

Now let's check that the first value we initialize `i` is, indeed `2` (which is a multiple of `2`) and the consecuence of this is that the loop is never going to be entered.  Se we can eliminate it completely, giving to:

```
    i = 2;
    if (i <= upperLevel && i % 2 == 0) {
        flag = 1;
    }
```

now, the second clause of the `if` test is always true, so we can take it off, giving:

```
    i = 2;
    if (i <= upperLevel) {
        flag = 1;
    }
```

Now, let's append the second part:

```
    i = 2;
    if (i <= upperLevel) {
        flag = 1;
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("%d", i);
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
```

so, the first thing we see here is that your `++i;` statement is nonsense, as it is the last statement to be
executed before exiting the program, so we can also take it off.

```
    i = 2;
    if (i <= upperLevel) {
        flag = 1;
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    return 0;
```

Now we see that you print the value of `i` only if the value of `flag` is zero, but `flag` only conserves its zero value if the value of `i > upperLevel`, and as `i` is fixed, the printing of `i` only occurs if you input a value of `upperlevel` that is less than `2`.

We can rewrite the above code as this:

```
    if (2 > upperLevel) {
        printf("%d", 2);
    }
```

Your program will print `2` only if you provide a value of `upperLevel` less than `2`.